# transaction can't be found when use cleos

Tags: cleos, rpc

when use cleos

```
chuck@chuck-MacBook-Pro:~/seaify/mine/coindream(master↑1|✚3) % cleos 
get transaction 
5af0762b78073cf20769f9ca884e3c4ec29d0d0f564fb4da9c1361e2b7302954 
(master↑1|✚3) Error 3200006: invalid http request Error Details: The 
server has rejected the request as invalid! Please verify this url is      
valid: http://mainnet.eoscalgary.io:80/v1/history/get_transaction If 
the condition persists, please contact the RPC server administrator for 
mainnet.eoscalgary.io!
```

when query at eosflare, https://eosflare.io/block/13602626, not found this transaction.

But when query at eospark, https://eospark.com/MainNet/block/13602626， it exists.

https://eospark.com/MainNet/tx/5af0762b78073cf20769f9ca884e3c4ec29d0d0f564fb4da9c1361e2b7302954, but i can't know it's status, success or failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your transaction on both block explorers, but eosflare labels it as a [`hard_fail` transaction](https://eosflare.io/tx/5af0762b78073cf20769f9ca884e3c4ec29d0d0f564fb4da9c1361e2b7302954). Therefore, I assume your transaction exceeded the resources it was entitled to without running into an `assert`.

For reference, according to [`/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/block.hpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/905e7c85714aee4286fa180ce946f15ceb4ce73c/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/block.hpp#L13-L19) there are several states of transactions:

```
  enum status_enum {
     executed  = 0, ///< succeed, no error handler executed
     soft_fail = 1, ///< objectively failed (not executed), error handler executed
     hard_fail = 2, ///< objectively failed and error handler objectively failed thus no state change
     delayed   = 3, ///< transaction delayed/deferred/scheduled for future execution
     expired   = 4  ///< transaction expired and storage space refuned to user
 };
```

The reason why `cleos` didn't find it may have something to do with the [read modes](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/read-modes) that the `nodeos` you were querrying was running as:

> - speculative : this includes the side effects of unconfirmed transactions.
> - head : this only includes the side effects of transactions which have been included in the produced and signed blocks that are part of the best chain nodeos
> - irreversible : this only includes side effects of transactions which have been confirmed by the network as irreversible.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a transaction, that means it went through.  If any part of a transaction fails, the entire transaction is rolled back.

See irreversible status: https://bloks.io/transaction/5af0762b78073cf20769f9ca884e3c4ec29d0d0f564fb4da9c1361e2b7302954